# Google cloud usage API

Tags: google-translate, google-cloud-billing

with my company we were interested in the translation API.

I need to know if there is a way to retrieve the usage state of an account for a specific period.
(For example I would like to be able to know that last month I translated X characters that corresponds to Y USD).

I'm sure that such an API exists, but I really can't find any reference to it.

Comment: "usage state of an account for a specific period" - do you mean number of translated characters per an IAM user account or service account?

Comment: Well, yes, I mean "translated character" as stated in the example.
I suppose for IAM user or with the highest granularity available anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translation API bills per character translated and counts translated characters for the whole project in order to create a bill for the customer.

To view your current billing status, including usage and your current bill, see the [Billing page](https://console.cloud.google.com/billing) (`GCP Console => Billing`). Billing reports for a particular service contain fields Product name (Translate), Usage (number of characters) and Cost.
See [Cloud Billing > Doc > View your billing reports and cost trends](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/reports)

More detailed information about consumption of the Translation API is not provided. At this time Translation API does not have such functionality.

A similar problem was raised on Issue Tracker in 2017 but to no avail: https://issuetracker.google.com/35903950.